# "I remember locking the door" vs "I remember the locking of the door"

Tags: difference, definite-article

> I remember locking the door

vs

> I remember the locking of the door

I remember the door being locked that night

What is the difference among these three meaningwise, and how to make gerund phrases negative in the given sentences... One more Question  His being insulted hurts me or Insulting him hurts me ...i am very confused...

Comment: First - I locked the door; second - someone locked the door.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael Harvey, do both of them mean the same, i remember the locking of the door and  I remember the door being locked..???are these the different ways of saying the same things??? When we use She resented Marry's being promoted it means the same as she resented the promoting of Marry???

Comment: (Sorry I'm not Michael Harvey!) **Broadly** (In general and with the exception of minor details) yes: they are different ways of saying the same thing. "*The locking of the door*" is an event: "At 11.00 each night I heard the locking of the door." "*The door being locked*" may be an event **or** it may describe the state of the door: "I remember the door being open/closed/locked all day." "Mary's being promoted" is good, but we would seldom say "the promoting of Mary". We might say "Mary's promotion."

Comment: They are different in meaning. The first: I remember **locking the door** - _I remember my own action of locking the door_. The second: I remember **the locking of the door** - _I remember the action (by someone not specified) of locking the door_

Comment: ‘The locking of the door’ sounds like some kind of formal ceremony performed by a Beefeater in full uniform rather than a casual event.

Comment: If i want to make a gerund phrase negative , can i use it as, I remember the not locking of the door , ??? It sounds strange to me, how should i make the gerund phrase negative for the second sentence: I remember the locking of the door..

Comment: I remember **not locking the door**.

Comment: But it is i think for the 1st sentence ( I remember locking the door, i locked the door , and i remember it) What will be for the second one ( I remember the locking of the door: )???

Comment: I remember the killing of George Floyd. But I hear someone say "I remember killing George Floyd" I'd call the cops and tell them racist Derek Chauvin was at large.

Comment: Yes , i have experienced the same thing many times, most people use active gerund phrase to convey passive meaning ..that's why i am very confused when to use active gerund ,passive and the+gerund +object  structure...